# Open Graph multilanguage description

Tags: javascript, html, multilingual, facebook-opengraph

I have problem about implementation Open Graph meta tags for for multiple languages. I have Web Project on ASP.NET MVC with multiply mechanism.

1. `domailname.com` - for English language
2. `domailname.com/pl-PL` - for Poland language
3. `domailname.com/ru-RU` - for Russian language

I need add Open Graph meta tags for 3 languages.
Example for my one English languages:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Title Project" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.domainname.com" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Description on English" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" /> //default
<meta property="og:image" content="url png for English verion">
```

For three different languages I need to add three different pictures with three different description.

Maybe I can add meta tags injection by jQuery or maybe do you have alternative method?